# Telethon - Cannot get difference since the account is not logged in: AuthKeyUnregisteredError

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

## AuthKeyUnregisteredError

I wrote my userbot on Teleton, everything was fine until I uploaded it to another hosting (in Germany) and clicked to end the session on the old hosting (in Helsinki). Every time I try to run the bot on a host or on a local machine, I get this error. this happens every time, and when this error occurs, it automatically terminates all sessions with the userbot

I launch the bot, enter the code that telegram sended to me, everything is good, and after some time (2-5 minutes, always different), when the bot needs to process some action, it gives this error
`2023-09-09 19:48:14,685 - telethon.client.updates - INFO - Cannot get difference since the account is not logged in: AuthKeyUnregisteredError`(but it was logged in)

I try to delete old sessions databases and rename it on

```
client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)
```

to

```
client = TelegramClient('userbot', api_id, api_hash)
```

i tried this like 10 times

Please help, if someone had that problem or knows how to fix it, let me know

Comment: You may want to check [ask]

Comment: `AuthKeyUnregisteredError` means you need to login again. Telegram can also terminate sessions if it detects suspicious activity. What this means is up to them.